# Image generation based on sketch

Tags: computer-vision, generative-models, gan

Are there any instances of image generation models, where an image (a very rough sketch) has been used as an input and was then augmented.

For example:

[image]

This could be a rough sketch, which is then augmented to an image that looks a little bit more like a dog (not a realistic one of course).

I was thinking about using GANs for this but I don't think that using this sketch instead of the random noise for the generator input will do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in [SketchyGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02753), whose TensorFlow implementation appears to be [here](https://github.com/wchen342/SketchyGAN)